# Postfix forwarding issue

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I've followed [flurdy's](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/) postfix set up, however I seem to have a problem when it comes to forwarding emails.  For example, in my maildb database - I have a table `Alias` which maps mail to a destination. For example: mail=`user@mymail.com` to destination=`user@gmail.com`.

When tailing the mail.logs I see>

```
postfix/smtpd[10912]: connect from mail-wi0-f170.google.com[209.85.212.170]
postfix/smtpd[10912]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-wi0-f170.google.com[209.85.212.170]: TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)
postgrey[29500]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mail-wi0-f170.google.com, client_address=209.85.212.170, sender=user@gmail.com, recipient=user@mymail.com
postgrey[29500]: cleaning up old logs...
postfix/smtpd[10912]: D5B6D6025: client=mail-wi0-f170.google.com[209.85.212.170]
postfix/cleanup[10927]: D5B6D6025: message-id=CA+fyp4yUhz=bYtUDns132ZWSo_A+nZasEDdPNdJFxiOdLPH-LQ@mail.gmail.com
postfix/qmgr[10881]: D5B6D6025: from=user@gmail.com, size=1913, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[10912]: disconnect from mail-wi0-f170.google.com[209.85.212.170]
postfix/smtp[10929]: D5B6D6025: to=user@gmail.com, orig_to=user@mymail.com, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[173.194.66.26]:25, delay=0.62, delays=0.21/0.02/0.17/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1359385356 f5si212603wja.5 - gsmtp)
postfix/qmgr[10881]: D5B6D6025: removed
```

However, user@gmail.com doesn't receive anything. I have the following postfix set up.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 10737418240
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination = mail.mymail.com, localhost, localhost.mymail.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = mymail.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction? Totally lost.

Cheers

Comment: Your log shows that the message was delivered successfully to google and google mail server accepted it. It appears to me user@gmail.com might have some filters, forward rules etc. Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: It's strange - there's no filters set up and nothing in Spam. Not sure how else to check... {edit} - just set forwarded to another gmail account, and appears to have worked. Strange why the first didn't.

Comment: check this link  http://superuser.com/questions/332389/postfix-forwarding-e-mail-to-gmail-not-working

Comment: Spot on! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> postfix/smtp[10929]: D5B6D6025: to=user@gmail.com,
>   orig_to=user@mymail.com, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[173.194.66.26]:25,
>   delay=0.62, delays=0.21/0.02/0.17/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250
>   2.0.0 OK 1359385356 f5si212603wja.5 - gsmtp)

This message was accepted by gmail; it is out of postfix's hands.

You'll have to ask Gmail, or possibly look in your spam folder.